# Solicitar permiso de activación de GPS dentro de la misma app

Tags: android, permisos, gps

Necesito ayuda con una solicitud de permiso de activación de **GPS**. Quiero que al momento de ejecutar mi actividad, si el **GPS** no esta activo me muestre el cuadro de dialogo que diga que la app solicita permiso para activarlo. Quisiera un método que funcione en todas las versiones de android, esto debido a que hay muchos ejemplos de marsmallow en adelante.

aquí mi código...

```
public class GPSActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

double mensaje1;
double mensaje2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
    } else {
        locationStart();
    }
}
private void locationStart() {
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Localizacion Local = new Localizacion();
    Local.setGPSActivity(this);
    assert mlocManager != null;
    final boolean gpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!gpsEnabled) {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
        return;
    }
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);
}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationStart();
        }
    }
}
public void setLocation(Location loc) {
    //Obtener la direccion de la calle a partir de la latitud y la longitud
    if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                String mensaje3 = DirCalle.getAddressLine(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
/* Aqui empieza la Clase Localizacion */
public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
    GPSActivity gpsActivity;

    public GPSActivity getGpsActivity() {
        return gpsActivity;
    }
    public void setGPSActivity(GPSActivity gpsActivity) {
        this.gpsActivity = gpsActivity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();
        mensaje1=loc.getLatitude();
        mensaje2=loc.getLongitude();
        this.gpsActivity.setLocation(loc);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GPS desactivado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"GPS Activado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.AVAILABLE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.d("debug", "LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
                break;
        }
    }

}
}
```

En ese código me envía a la configuración del smartphone para que sea el mismo usuario que lo active, me parece mucho mejor que dentro de la app solo pregunte.. "Una aplicación solicita la activacion del GPS, Desea activarlo? aceptar - cancelar"

Comment: Por si te sirve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nenaJb66JL8

Comment: en el video hacen basicamente lo que estoy haciendo, me envia a la configuracion del smarphone, lo que quiero es que al momento del onClick me muestre el dialogo donde me diga que la app requiere activacion del GPS y al aceptar se active dentro de la misma app, sin mandarme a hacer la activacion manualmente, ya que entre mas rapido y facil sea la activacion del mismo, mejor para la app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo lo que necesitas es ver la documentacion de Android la cual esta aqui https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419

En resumen seria algo asi

```
// esto muestra el dialogo de permisos
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, /* Este codigo es para identificar tu request */ 1);
```

Despues debes sobreescribir en tu activity el metodo **onRequestPermissionsResult**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case 1 /* El codigo que puse a mi request */: {
      // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
      if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // aqui ya tengo permisos
      } else {
        // aqui no tengo permisos
      }
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Para verificar si los permisos han sido concedidos tienes 2 opciones

Con este verificas si ya tiene concedido los permisos

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

y

Con este verificas si el usuario ha rechazado los permisos anteriormente marcando la casilla de "no volver a preguntar"

```
ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo siento pero **el mensaje que muestra el sistema operativo para que confirme el usuario si acepta o no el permiso, no puede ser modificado**, el usuario tiene la decisión de aceptar o no este permiso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso en el que la aplicación requiera este permiso pueda funcionar correctamente, puedes mostrar previamente un diálogo comentando la razón por la cual le sugieres aceptar el permiso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: exactamente ese mensaje es el que quiero mostrar, el que no puede ser modificado, para que no me envie a la configuracion a hacerlo manualmente, sino que con solo clickear permitir automaticamente me active el GPS y comience a realizar las siguientes acciones. Lo que pasa es que donde muestran ese ejemplo lo hacen con marsmallow en adelante y necesito que sea algo general, que funcione independientemente la version del sistema operativo.