# Permiso para descargar en tarjeta sd (removible) android

Tags: android, android-permissions

Estoy tratando de descargar un archivo mediante la libreria Fetch (https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch) y que se guarde en la raiz de la tarjeta sd externa, pero cuando lo intento, me marca permiso denegado. he investigado que para escribir en la sd externa es necesario utilizar el framewrok de almacenamiento (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider?hl=es-419) pero no logro entender bien como utilizarlo, cabe mencionar que ya tengo los permisos de escritura en el manifest y en ejecución.

este es mi codigo:

```
                Fetch fetch;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
            FetchConfiguration fetchConfiguration = new FetchConfiguration.Builder(this)
                            .setDownloadConcurrentLimit(3)
                            .build();

                    fetch = Fetch.Impl.getInstance(fetchConfiguration);



                    fetch.addListener(new FetchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdded(Download download) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onQueued(Download download, boolean b) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Queued",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onWaitingNetwork(Download download) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Download download) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Completed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Download download, com.tonyodev.fetch2.Error error, Throwable throwable) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error "+error.getThrowable(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDownloadBlockUpdated(Download download, DownloadBlock downloadBlock, int i) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStarted(Download download, List<? extends DownloadBlock> list, int i) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(Download download, long l, long l1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Progres "+l,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPaused(Download download) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResumed(Download download) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(Download download) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onRemoved(Download download) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDeleted(Download download) {

                        }
                    });

solicitarPermiso();

        }


        private void descargar(){
            String url = "https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4";
            String file = "/storage/sdcard/archivo.mp4";
            request = new Request(url, file);
            request.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);
            request.setNetworkType(NetworkType.ALL);
            request.addHeader("clientKey", "SD78DF93_3947&MVNGHE1WONG");
            fetch.enqueue(request, updatedRequest -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exito enqueue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }, error -> {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error enqueue"+error.getThrowable(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });
        }

    public void solicitarPermiso(){
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
            }else {
descargar();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            if (requestCode == 1){
                if (!(grantResults.length ==1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                    android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Aviso")
                            .setMessage("Es necesario el permiso de archivos para descargar")
                            .setPositiveButton("Dar Permiso", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    solicitarPermiso();
                                }
                            }).setCancelable(false)
                            .show();
                }else {
descargar();
                }
            }
        }
```

Log:

```
E/ERROR_TAG: Error enqueuejava.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ademas de tenerlo en el manifest? haz pedido los permisos de escritura ya en la aplicacion. Luego de Android 6.0 (N) debes pedir los permisos  . Un ejemplo para que te guies https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177528/solicitar-permiso-de-activaci%C3%B3n-de-gps-dentro-de-la-misma-app

Comment: Si cómo menciono ya solicite los permisos durante ejecución cómo lo menciona aquí https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419 y puedo descargar el archivo en la dirección que retorna getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() pero lo guarda en la memoria interna no en la secundaria, la tarjeta SD.